# E-mailing form data with php

Tags: php

I have serached through previous questions and have had no luck finding the answer.

I want to simply send the imformation from my form to be e-mailed to me.here is my code for form.

```
<form action="http://bikesnwines.com/html_form_send.php" method="post" name="form1">        <strong>Your Details:</strong>Full name:
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="fullname" size="30" />
E-mail Address:
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="email_from" size="30" />Date of Visit:
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="date" size="30" />
<strong>Accomodation:</strong>

<a href="http://www.bikesnwines.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/val-du-charron-    12+-1.jpg"><img class="size-medium wp-image-1382 alignnone" alt="val-du-charron-12+ (1)"     src="http://www.bikesnwines.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/val-du-charron-12+-1-    300x125.jpg" width="400" height="170" /></a>
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong><a title="Val Du Charron"     href="http://vdcwines.com/" target="_blank">Val Du Charron Wine Estate</a></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>Length of Stay:</strong>1 Night Stay only<strong></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>Optional Extra's:</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: left;"><input type="checkbox" name="extra1" value="MTB"     />Mountain Biking Tours<input type="checkbox" name="extra1" value="Spa" />Spa     Treatements<input type="checkbox" name="extra1" value="Olive" />Olive Grove Tour and     Tasting<input type="checkbox" name="extra1" value="Fishing" />Bass Fishing<input     type="checkbox" name="extra1" value="HorseRide" />Horse Riding</p>
<strong>Cycling Levels:</strong>
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="Relaxed" />Relaxed
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="Moderate" />Moderate
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="Challenging" />Challenging

<strong>Transport:</strong>
<input type="radio" name="transport" value="Car Hire" />Car Hire
<input type="radio" name="transport" value="Transfers" />Airport or other Transfers
<input type="radio" name="transport" value="Self Drive" />Self Drive

Comments:
<textarea cols="25" maxlength="1000" name="comments" rows="6"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Enquire Now" />

</form>
```

and the php I am using

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
$email_to = "bookings@bikesnwines.com";

$email_subject = "Wellington Overnight Requests";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.     ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
    }

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['fullname']) ||
isset($_POST['email_from']) ||
isset($_POST['date']) ||
isset($_POST['extra1']) ||
    !isset($_POST['difficulty']) ||
    !isset($_POST['transport']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you     submitted.');       
    }

$fullname = $_POST['fullname']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email_from']; // required
$date = $_POST['date']; // required
$extra1 = $_POST['extra1']; // not required
$difficulty = $_POST['difficulty']; // required
$transport = $_POST['transport']; // required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$fullname)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';


}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($fullname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Date of Stay: ".clean_string($date)."\n";
$email_message .= "Optional Extra's: ".clean_string($extra1)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

//redirect to thank for registering page
header( 'Location: http://raceinterface.co.za/thank-you-for-registering/' ) ;
}
?>
```

when you submit it just opens a blank page.. 
I'm a bit blonde.. but super stuck..

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about too localized.

Answer (score 6):

For a start, you do not have a field named simply 'email'. Try changing `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {` to `if(isset($_POST['email_from'])) {`

Answer (score 0):

The name in the form for the input email is 'email_from', and in the php code, you have written 'if (!isset($_POST['email'])' . Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a variable email in your form.
So if you check in your php for $_POST['email'] it is never set.

You should build in an "else" after } in your .php.